# Today in Oracle Unix date

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a field which stores the date in a Unix timestamp.

Instead of having to translate the test ie

```
TO_DATE( TO_CHAR( TO_DATE('19700101', 'yyyymmdd') + + ( FLOOR( ph.change_date / 24 / 60 / 60)))) = '07-NOV-2020'
```

I want to just say

```
ph.change_date = Todays Date
```

But have that as a Unix Timestamp.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Note, Unix timestamp are based on 1970-01-01 00:00:00 **UTC** - you may have to consider this in your query if your database server runs not on UTC time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unix time is in the UTC time zone; do not naively use `SYSDATE` as it may be in the wrong time zone. Use `SYSTIMESTAMP` and convert it to `UTC`:

```sql
WHERE ph.change_date >= ( TRUNC( SYSTIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' ) - DATE '1970-01-01' ) * 24 *60 * 60
AND   ph.change_date <  ( TRUNC( ( SYSTIMESTAMP + INTERVAL '1' DAY ) AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' ) - DATE '1970-01-01' ) * 24 *60 * 60
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest:

```
ts >= (trunc(sysdate) - date '1970-01-01') * 24 * 60 * 60 and
ts >= (trunc(sysdate) + 1 - date '1970-01-01') * 24 * 60 * 60
```

This is index-compatible, so it can make use of an index on `ts`.

If you don't care about that, this is an alternative:

```
trunc(date '1970-01-01' + ts * interval '1' second) = trunc(sysdate)
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon so for example it would be trunc((date '1970-01-01' + ph.change_date * interval '1' second)) = trunc(sysdate)

Comment: This is wrong as Unix timestamps are in the UTC time zone and `SYSDATE` is likely to be for a different time zone.